# Accessing MySQL relations with Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

How do you access a MySQL relation using RoR?

Comment: It sounds like you need to go through a Rails tutorial to understand how everything works (Google for Rails 2.0 tutorial and you'll find plenty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toby is right. You need to learn about table relationships using ActiveRecord.

**The gist**. You need to put the following codes in your models. Here is an example.

In User model:

```
has_many :addresses
```

In the Address model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

This is for a one to many relationship.

This [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) should give you all the help you need.

You can also refer to the rails documentation by going to [this site](http://www.gotapi.com/rubyrails) and enter 'belongs_to' in the search box. That will bring you to the relevant page.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't really make sense.

Rails works with ActiveRecord which handles all sorts of complex database relationships. Check the AR documentation for details.